# Couldn't import Django after updating to windows 11

Tags: python, django

When I run "python manage.py runserver" the following error occurs:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "F:\blear\manage.py", line 10, in main
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\blear\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\blear\manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

how can I solve.
ps: this error occurred after updating to windows 11
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naIoI.png)
i hope solve this problem

Comment: check the python you are using, and pip install django in worst case

Comment: Each major version of Python (3.8, 3.9, 3.10, etc) has its own separate area for installing modules.  Sounds like you had django installed for some earlier version of python, but Windows 11 installed a newer version.  So you just need to install django for that version.

Comment: If you have created the virtual environment then make sure that you activate it.